# How does the syntax to specify file type changes in Gitlab's CI rules work?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My file structure consits of 2 main directories, `resources` and `src`, `resources` has images in a subdirectory, and various json files. `src` has many nested directories with `.ts` files in each:

```
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
│ 
├── .docker
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── aBashScript.sh
│ 
├── resources
│   ├── data.json
│   └── images
│       └── manyimages.png
│
├── src
│   ├── subdirectory1
│   └── NestedDirectories
│
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── tsconfig.eslint.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── eslintrc.json
└── prettierrc.json
```

My `gitlab-ci.yml` has two stages, `build` and `deploy`
**What I want:**
1- If it's a commit on branches "main" or "dev" and If anything that affects the actual project changes, run `build`.
That is anything under `resources`, or `src` (and their nested directories), the `Dockerfile`, `package.json` and `package-lock.json`
I'd be content with "any `.ts` file changed" too, since all other criteria is *usually* only when this happens.
2- If `build` ran and it's a commit on the default branch ("main") then run the `deploy` stage.
Also for clarification when I say there's a commit on branch X, I mean as in an accepted merge request, or well an actual change on that branch. At some point in my tinkering it was running on (non accepted) merge requests, but I forgot what I changed to fix that.

**What happens:**
1- If I specify the `changes` rule on build then it *never* runs, however even if build doesn't run deploy always runs (if on branch "main")

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: project

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_image:
    stage: build
    image: docker:20.10.16
    services:
        - docker:20.10.16-dind
    variables:
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    before_script:
        - echo $REGISTRY_PASS | docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin
    script:
    - |
        if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
        tag="latest"
        echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = '$tag'"
        else
        tag="$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
        fi
    - docker build -f .docker/Dockerfile -t $REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG-$tag .
    - docker push $REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG-$tag
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
          changes:
            - \*.ts
            - \*.json
            - Dockerfile

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
    - chmod SSH_KEY
    script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY $VPS "
        echo $REGISTRY_PASS | docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin &&
        cd project &&
        docker-compose pull &&
        docker-compose up -d"
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
```

This is the most basic one I could cobble up, basically excluding just the readme, but the `build` stage doesn't run (deploy does run even if build didn't)

Normally this is something I'd be able to "brute force" figure out myself, but to avoid uselessly modifying my files to test the changes rule, I've only been able to test this when making actual modifications to the project.
There seems to be a lot of examples from questions and tutorials out there, but I think something is off with my file structure as I've had no luck copying their changes rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `changes:` entries are glob patterns, not regex. So in order for you to match `.ts` files in any directory, you'll need to use `"**/*.ts"` not `*.ts` (which would only match files in the root).

```yaml
changes:
  - "**/*.ts"
  - "**/*.json"
  # ...
```

> If build ran and it's a commit on the default branch ("main") then run the deploy stage.

To get this effect, you'll want your `deploy` job to share some of the rules of your build job.

```yaml
deploy:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
      changes:
        - Dockerfile
        - "**/*.ts"
        - "**/*.json"
```

Or a little fancier way that reduces code duplication:

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
      when: never  # only deploy on default branch
    - !reference [build_image, rules]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed thinking it was the same as regex.  
This works perfectly, but I'm still curious on the change with the deploy part, is there a difference between checking if it's not default branch (using when:never) vs just checking if it is the default branch (and not using when:never) ?

Comment: There's no particular reason why it has to be done the way I did it. It's just what immediately came to mind for me. You could actually just use `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` and combine the `changes:` key into the same rule and just have 1 rule. I think my initial thought was that I would use `- !reference [build_image, rules]` (the negative rule would then be important to prevent running on other branches and stop rule matching) for the second rule, but I decided against it for purpose of clarity... I'll make an edit that might explain this better... @DavidPH